# How can i change icon or value help indicator in sap.m.Input?

Tags: user-interface, sapui5

I am Using a Input field with a valueHelpRequest function but i need to change the icon or value help indicator to a custom icon. Can we do this and if yes how? Following is my piece of code:

```
var oin1 = new sap.m.Input("id1",{
        type:"Text", 
        placeholder:"Enter name",
        editable:true,showValueHelp:true, 
        valueHelpRequest:function(){
        sap.m.MessageToast.show("Value help request called !",{duration: 500})
     }});
```

You can see the Input field here:

[image: You can see the Input field here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Input control doesn't allow you to specify which icon should be used as value-help icon. You can see in line 415 of [Input.js](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Input.js) that the value help icon is hard-coded.

However, if you need a version of the input control that does allow you to specify which icon is used, I would suggest to create a custom Input control. This Input control could be as simple as subclass of the standard UI5 Input control. And then just override its _getValueHelpIcon method.